# Github push failed in IntelliJ

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I created 2 repos by github MacOS desktop in my project, using my new github account. But when I am trying to push commits through IntelliJ, there is a 403 error, but I can push successfully in github Desktop.

> remote: Permission to Auird/OJ.git denied to auicheng.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Auird/OJ.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

auicheng is my previous account. 
I did change account setting in IntelliJ, and I didn't use SSH.
How can I solve this?

Comment: what were the entire commands you used?

Comment: I didn't use command line, I just use InteillJ's git menu to push it.

Comment: I don't currently have IntelliJ, but have you ensured that your local and remote are at the same stage?

Comment: I'm not sure, could tell me how to check that? thank you

Comment: check the answer, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently don't have IntelliJ installed, but you might want do push it from your terminal as a second option. You can use the steps below:

1. After creating your new repository on git, in the directory you're working on, run `git init`. Which should "Initialized empty git repository in ....git".
2. Run `git add .` This should add add all your files.
3. You can then commit you added files with a message you will choose `git commit -m "you_can_type_whatever_message_you_choose"`
4. You can now tell git to add your commited files to a remote location you created, which should make git aware of your remote repository.
   `git remote add origin https://github.com/Auird/OJ.git/`
5. You might want to pull to ensure that you bring your local branch up-to-date with its remote version. `git pull origin master`
6. After all this done successfully, you can then push using `git push -u origin master`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Auird/OJ.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I follow your instructions, and I get results above.

Comment: I have made some little corrections, maybe you can check it now

Comment: @AuiCheng were you able to push it successfully?

Comment: Yes, I push it successfully. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AuiCheng oh great to hear that, you can accept the answer then