# Unable to push repository to Github

Tags: java, github, intellij-15

I am trying to push some code to my Github repository.
I have a base repository on Github, that I pulled on IntelliJ. After making changes, I am trying to push it back to Github. But, I keep getting the following error :
remote: Permission to xxxxxx.git denied to xxxxxx.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
I am new to both Github and IntelliJ and I have no idea about what I am doing wrong.

I even tried to push the repository from a terminal. But, got the same error

λ git push
info: please complete authentication in your browser...
remote: Permission to springframeworkguru/spring5webapp.git denied to beingmohitagwl.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring5webapp.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Have you tried using SSH? If not give it a shot, it will sort out the issue you are facing.
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: Duplicate of [Github push failed in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354077/github-push-failed-in-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my repository was forked from someone else's repo. So, I had to change the owner of my repo to allow git push.

Initially :

λ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/notMyRepo/app.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/notMyRepo/app.git (push)

I changed it by :
λ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myRepo/app